# Worklight Custom Authenticator URL not found

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

i've implemented custom authentication with a form and custom authentication component (java-based ldap in-house component).
It was fine until i changed few js and html on client-side.
I tried to restart the server, rebuild the apps, nothing worked.

Now, Sometimes, I've got the following issue in my development environment and the authentication fails randomly:

```
[30/09/13 15:30:39:805 CEST] 0000004e com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension                            W SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url
[30/09/13 15:30:39:811 CEST] 0000004e com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter            E FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:496)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:192)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:196)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4499)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is there a way to trouble-shoot this?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot submit authentication before it was triggered. /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url will exist only AFTER you've requested something protected by a respective realm. Most simple way is to invoke WL.Client.login("your-realm").

Comment: that's right... in my code, i was using a form to custom auth before calling a protected resource :S

Comment: So if your page starts with a login form, do you just call WL.Client.login on device ready?

Comment: Yes, this is the idea. You cannot submit form unless you've received it first.